# Google Maps V2 is not being displayed

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I followed the below tutorial to show map on device and I was able to do that when I ran the project from my laptop, but when the same code is run on other laptop the map is not showing up.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614946/Android-google-map-api-v2-setup

Thanks in advance

Comment: post the releavant code

Comment: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11923): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
E/Google Maps Android API(11923): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
02-10 15:42:23.232: E/Google Maps Android API(11923): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: com.example.splitpanelayout, API Key: I have placed my key here, Certificate Fingerprint: 3370A518590C195C0E778CD3ECC9FE1661BF646F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my guess u haven't generate `API-Key` for both laptops as `SHA-1 fingerprint` **is different of ur laptop and the other laptop** API key will not work if u have single API key for both laptops. Use first API-Key for ur laptop and
Generate another key using `other laptop's SHA-1 fingerprint;package name` and replace `API Key` in 2nd laptop's manifest which is newly generated.